# page curling in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-animation

i am doing app for **Ebook Reader**. it is needed page curling for the book page turn over. i have book as HTML and show it in a web view. for page turning i need page curling feature for the ebook reader. i have googled it but i does not get any related answers. all the answers are redirected me to page curling for image. it is not used for me. because i am showing HTML in web view. i am not displaying an image. i do not know how to do page curling for ebook reader. please help me. any thoughts that appreciated.

Comment: i am also having the same problem ,Did you get any solution??

Comment: @Daniel, Sorry i didn't get solution. if you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: actually i am also working for ebook reader so for image example are there but not getting anything for webview

Comment: i am also working on same type of application can you help how to create ebook reader in webview.

Answer (score 0):

There is a open source project called [Page Curl for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/) which allows you to flip pages which uses only android canvas.

Then there is also a OpenGL page curl open source project on [github](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/).

Comment: hi i have already seen the github code. it is page curling for image not html page.  i am doing ebook reader so image page curling is not used. please help me.

Comment: please see my edited question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997363/page-curling-in-android

Comment: I would use the a "non-OpenGL"(2D) page curling effect like the one mentioned above -- [Page Curl for Android](https://sites.google.com/site/hnimblog/bai-viet-2/android-hieu-ung-lat-trang-khong-dung-opengl) -- or there is another one, that I found but it's in Vietnamese -- [here](https://sites.google.com/site/hnimblog/bai-viet-2/android-hieu-ung-lat-trang-khong-dung-opengl) --. It shouldn't be too hard to use a WebView instead of the canvas and try to implement the curl effect. In the examples you have the algorithm so all you need is to put the 2 together.