# Add WebView with PageCurl effect in Android

Tags: android, webview, page-curl

I am trying to display certain text in android which has text with numbers and bullets which I have achieved by using a HTML page. I am also familiar on how to add the webview but as I am using a PageCurl, I am unable to display the contents of webview in android.

**CODE :**

```
private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.layout.sample, R.layout.sample,
                R.layout.sample, R.layout.sample, R.layout.sample,
                R.layout.sample };
```

This is how I am using a page curl, all the XML files will be added to an array to be displayed in a page curl. This is what I have tried so far :

```
View sample = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample,null);
we = (WebView) sample.findViewById(R.id.admission_procedure_webview);
we.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/admission_prcedure.html");
```

I know its really dumb but I had to try something. I googled all over but was unable to find any solid lead. Some had even mentioned that it is impossible to achieve it. Found em at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051744/how-to-do-curl-effect-on-html-pages-instead-of-image-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997363/page-curling-in-android). I am using one of the most popular page curl [library.](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/)

How do I add a web view to page curl ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I finally found a library which helps in achieving the page TURN in android with webview. Please be noted that its not page curl but has a decent effect for turning page. You can find the library [here](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip). Finally, I have also come to a conclusion that it is not possible to achieve Webview with a page curl. Please let me know if someone has found how to add web view with a page curl.